# dictionary of values/lists to list of dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

Given a dictionary containing lists with different lengths but not only, e.g.

```
d = {foo: 'hello', bar: [0, 2], baz: [1, 2, 3]}
```

I would like to create a list of all possible combinations where each combination is a dictionary:

```
l = [{foo: 'hello', bar: 0, baz: 1},
     {foo: 'hello', bar: 0, baz: 2},
     {foo: 'hello', bar: 0, baz: 3},
     {foo: 'hello', bar: 2, baz: 1},
     {foo: 'hello', bar: 2, baz: 2},
     {foo: 'hello', bar: 2, baz: 3}]
```

The order does not matter here and I don't need to transform back the list into a dictionary.

It is of course possible to perform this operation with Python loops but I'm looking for a solution which is more efficient and/or more elegant.

Comment: is `foo` any different than `bar` and `baz`? Because that's the only element that's not a list.

Comment: Indeed, foo is not a list. But if it's simpler with lists only, it's ok for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm below answers the question in a generic way:

```
def list_of_dictionaries(self, dictionary):
  # values which are not lists are forced to be lists
  for k, v in dictionary.items():
    if type(v) is not list:
        dictionary[k] = [v]

  # list all combinations of values
  combinations = [list(x) for x in dictionary.values() if isinstance(x, list)]
  combinations = list(itertools.product(*combinations))

  # create list of dictionaries
  list_of_dicts = []
  for values in combinations:
    dict_element = {}
    for i, k in enumerate(dictionary.keys()):
        dict_element[k] = values[i]
    list_of_dicts.append(dict_element)

  return list_of_dicts
```

Answer (score 2):

Itertools would be great for this. The code could look something like this:

```
import itertools

d = {'foo': 'hello', 'bar': [0, 2], 'baz': [1, 2, 3]}
a = [list(x) for x in d.values() if isinstance(x, list)]
constant_values = [x for x in d.values() if x not in a]
keys = d.keys()

combinations = list(itertools.product(*a))
```

Just transform it into a dictionary as the last step using constant_values and keys

Comment: combinations: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)]

Comment: Actually, it works if you change 'hello' to ['hello']. But is it not possible to release this constraint here and keep 'hello' as it is?

Comment: Furthermore, it returns a list of tuples instead of a list of dictionaries. All keys are lost and I don't know how to "just transform it into a dictionary as the last step".

Comment: I edited my question with a possible algorithm deduced from DSteman's answer (thank you) but I am pretty sure it's not a very smart implementation.

Comment: The tuples outputted by my code are corresponding to the values of bar and baz, respectively. On tuple has two values because foo is not a list, thus doesn't contain multiple values, thus doesn't need to be taken into account when finding all combinations.

Comment: I gave you some extra hints, check my revised answer

Comment: Thank you DSteman. Unfortunately, the expected output in my initial question is a list of dictionaries which contains foo and its value even though it is not a list.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the answer by @DSteman is basically correct and they have given you the tools you need to solve your issue.

I see you are getting stuck on how to finish up given their excellent starting suggestion. So here is a simpler more explicit version that lacks the flexibility they have included but directly produces the result you seek.

If you feel this solves your question I strongly recommend you revisit their answer and consider it as the "solution".

```
import itertools

data_in = {"foo": "hello", "bar": [0, 2], "baz": [1, 2, 3]}
data_out = [
    {"foo": data_in["foo"], "bar": c[0], "baz": c[1]}
    for c in itertools.product(data_in["bar"], data_in["baz"])
]

print(data_out)
```

this will produce:

```
[
    {'foo': 'hello', 'bar': 0, 'baz': 1},
    {'foo': 'hello', 'bar': 0, 'baz': 2},
    {'foo': 'hello', 'bar': 0, 'baz': 3},
    {'foo': 'hello', 'bar': 2, 'baz': 1},
    {'foo': 'hello', 'bar': 2, 'baz': 2},
    {'foo': 'hello', 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3}
]
```

Comment: Thank you JonSG. The main drawback of your very interesting answer is that it relies on the assumption that the input dictionary will have the same structure as the one given as an example. Therefore, it is less general than the answer I deduced from DSteman's answer, even though your own answer is by far more elegant than mine.